# character table and nilpotency/solubility

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters, nilpotence, solvable-groups

In the book on Character Theory by Huppert, the author asserts that

> Character table determines nilpotency (class) and solubility (class) of a group.

I have a simple question about this. Everyone agrees that character table of $G$ determines its center and commutator quotient, hence a first step towards nilpotency or solubility.

But then, to determine second center ($Z_2(G)$) or second commutator ($[G',G']$) we have to look for character table of $G/Z(G)$ (or ...). In other words, just character table of $G$ *may* not be sufficient.

Thus, I was confused with authors above assertion.

**Question:** Is there any different way to see that character table of a group determines nilpotency or solubility?

To be more simple, I was concerning question like

**Question:** Suppose we have character table of a $p$-group. (We know that the group is nilpotent even without character table, but can we deduce this from character table?  Can we determine its nilpotency class?

Comment: A representation of G/Z is more or less the same thing as a representation of G which has Z in its kernel.

Comment: In general, from a character table, you can identify the normal subgroups of $G$ as unions of conjugacy classes, and determine the character tables of all of their quotient groups.